# Case statement criteria not working SQL

Tags: sql

I'm having issues with the following case statement. I figure I can do it two ways but neither are working for me. I have two columns I'm using to derive the data.

Basically the criteria is as follows:

> When erpol.n_pol is blank, use idv.n_pol, otherwise use erpol.n_pol.

I want to incorporate that if they are both blank - use `ks.n_pol`. Another way of identifying when to use `ks.n_pol` is if the first 3 letters of `dt.n_pol` are "OAC" which I have also tried as you can see.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

It is working now as is (with the `substring` commented out) I just need to be able to add the "if they are both blank use ks.n_pol to it".

```
 ,dt.i_pol as "Policy_Number"
 , (case
 when erpol.n_pol is null then idv.n_pol
/*when substr(dt.i_pol,1,3)= 'OAC' then ks.n_pol*/
else erpol.n_pol end) as "Policy_Name"
,0 as "Division_Number"
,d_dby as "Disability_Date"
,0 as "Months_Since_Disability_Date"
,0 as "First_Payment_Date"
,0 as "Last_Payment_Date"
,0 as "Last_Benefit_Paidto_Date"
,dys as "Days_Since_Last_Paidto"


from dt
```

Comment: What database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE`

eg

```
COALESCE (erpol.n_pol,idv.n_pol, ks.n_pol)
```

If there's a danger of all 3 being null, then add a default to the end

```
COALESCE (erpol.n_pol,idv.n_pol, ks.n_pol, 'default')
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that in this particular case @podiluska's solution is **way** better, your query fails because as soon as the first field is NULL, the first option gets chosen.

I am not sure about execution order in `CASE WHEN`, but usually the most restrictive conditions go first, so:

```
(CASE WHEN erpol.n_pol IS NULL AND idv.n_pol IS NULL THEN ks.n_pol
      WHEN erpol.n_pol IS NULL THEN idv.n_pol
      ELSE erpol.n_pol END)
```

You can replace the first WHEN conditions with the "OAC" test if you're sure that this is equivalent to both `erpol` and `idv` having a `NULL` `n_pol`.

Comment: I was actually pouting for arriving late :-)

Answer (score 0):

> It is working now as is (with the substring commented out) I just need to be able to add the "if they are both blank use ks.n_pol to it".

This should work:

```
ISNULL(ISNULL(erpol.n_pol, idv.n_pol), ks.n_pol)
```